# Download artifact with dependency URL

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to get an URL that downloads an Artifact from Artifactory with **all it's transitive dependencies?**

I know that it is possible on the command line with different tools(maven, gradle etc) but we have some users that are non technical.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer's no, Artifactory does not manage transitive dependencies for any single artifact, and cannot make decisions by itself about what transitive dependencies (and what versions or from where) it should fetch - most of that logic usually resides in the tool you're using.

The exceptions for this are:

1. Textual (shallow) analysis provided during index: i.e. debian / npm / docker artifacts also hold their dependencies as `properties` set on the artifact.
2. The Build support module knows about the dependencies your build reported when deploying the `Build Info` (if you used an Artifactory plugin)

But also in these cases Artifactory does not support any way of getting an Artifact with its dependencies - that's what build tools and dependency/package managers are for.